# jQuery, using .queue() to cascade CSS toggleClass()

Tags: jquery, queue, css-transitions

I have many many elements that I need to toggle the css class of on user click.The transitions all happen at once and hence is very slow: I want the transition from classes properties to happen one after the other after a small delay, like you would with an `animate()` callback. Since `removeClass()`, `addClass() & toggleClass()` don't have callbacks, I have been struggling to make that work.

I have looked [here](http://learn.jquery.com/effects/uses-of-queue-and-dequeue/) and on the jquery doc, but I am still confused.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

[JSFiddle is here.](http://jsfiddle.net/joshuasnowball/FrGaq/7/)

```
    $(".vanilla").click(function () {
    colorThread(this);
});


function colorThread(clickedMsg) {
    itemId = $(clickedMsg).attr('id');
    pointerForward = itemId;
    pointerBackward = itemId - 1;
    classList = clickedMsg.classList;
    classList = classList[0];
    idArray = $('.' + classList)
        .map(function () {
        return this.id;
    });


    while (pointerForward < idArray.length || pointerBackward >= 0) {
        var xF = $('#' + idArray[pointerForward]);
        var xB = $('#' + idArray[pointerBackward]);
        var theQueue = $({});

        theQueue.queue("transition", function (next) {
            xF.toggleClass("vanilla-red");
            next();
        }).dequeue("transition").queue("transition", function (next) {
            xB.toggleClass("vanilla-red");
            next();
        }).delay(200).dequeue("transition");

            pointerBackward--;
            pointerForward++;

    }
}
```

Comment: It's worth mentioning that an `id` *cannot* begin with a number.

Comment: Unless you're using asynchronous operations like animations or delays, I don't know why you'd need `.queue()`.

Comment: @jfriend00: well, it seems to be one of the few option to add delay to a css class transition and it seemed a valid approach to the problem but i might be wrong. do you have any suggestions?

Comment: `setTimeout()` will work just fine to toggle the next class a certain amount of time after the first one or you can listen for the `transitionEnd` event that signals the end of a CSS transition and start the next one at that point.  I'm sure you can make `.queue()` - I've just never found it the easiest or clearest way of solving most problems.  Keep in mind that `.toggleClass()` is a synchronous operation so it doesn't really help anythning to put successive `.toggleClass()` operations in the queue.  It's no different than just calling them sequentially.

Comment: @jfriend00 ah, make sense. I've overlooked setTimeout and got lured into focusing on queue() instead of what i wanted to achieve. thx for the input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might be misinterpreting what you want, but...

If you include the JQuery UI library, the `.toggleClass()` function can be used like `.animate()` with a delay and a callback.

Then you can do something like this:

```
$(".vanilla").click(function () {
    colorThread($(this));
});

function colorThread($div) {
    $div.toggleClass('vanilla-red', 100, function () {
        (function togglePrev($div) {
            $div.toggleClass('vanilla-red', 100, function () {
                togglePrev($div.prev());
            });
        })($div.prev());
        (function toggleNext($div) {
            $div.toggleClass('vanilla-red', 100, function () {
                toggleNext($div.next());
            });
        })($div.next());
    });
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4kuFV/)

If you don't really care if the class is animated, but just want a delay between the toggling of the different elements, you can use `setTimeout` instead. (In this case you don't need to include the JQuery UI library).

```
function colorThread($div) {
    $div.toggleClass('vanilla-red');
    setTimeout(function () {
        (function togglePrev($div) {
            $div.toggleClass('vanilla-red');
            setTimeout(function() {
                togglePrev($div.prev());
            }, 100);
        })($div.prev());
        (function toggleNext($div) {
            $div.toggleClass('vanilla-red');
            setTimeout(function() {
                toggleNext($div.next());
            }, 100);
        })($div.next());
    }, 100);
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/35uNW/)

Comment: great! yes, this is exactly what i wanted to achieve, in a more confuse, more complicated way. thanks!